# Could I put a condition to filter my COUNT clause? mysql

Tags: mysql, database, select, count, conditional-statements

I will solely explain what's related to the question and omit any other unrelated details.

**Current Situation:**

I have two tables, coin and users.

**`coin`** has three fields `id, uid, fid.` 
Coin table relates between users (who already registered in the system and are able to invite friends) and their friends (who already has accepted the invitation and also became members.) -the table only stores successful registrations after being invited-

**`id`** is unique index.
**`uid`** is to store users id.
**`fid`** is to store friends id (the friend who accepted the invitation and became a member of the system).

**`users`** has the usual info about users such as `id, fname, lname, email` ...etc and `date_create`

**Objective:** 
To find the **winners** who had made most invitations. In other words. 
To find top user(s) who have made the greatest number of invitation and their invited friends must have registered before 2012-08-31. Date is stored in table 'users' column date_create. Date Format is yyyy-mm-dd

Example-

```
Table coin

    id uid fid 
    1  333 777   
    2  444 888       
    3  555 999       
    4  333 123         
    5  444 456         
    6  333 789   

Table users
    id   date_create
    333  2012-07-15
    444  2012-07-20
    555  2012-07-25
    777  2012-07-25
    888  2012-07-25
    999  2012-10-02   <-- I don't need this to be counted
    123  2012-07-25
    456  2012-07-25
    789  2012-07-25
```

means user 333 has the most number of invitation (invited 3 users) -> 777,123 and 789
and user 444 invited 2 users and user 555 only invited 1 user, but for 555 it will not be counted since his friend (999)  registered after 2012-08-31

What i want is user

```
333 has made 3 invitations before 2012-08-31. 
444 has made 2 invitations before 2012-08-31.
```

What i did so far is: [TOTALLY NOT SURE ABOUT THIS]

```
SELECT
  c.uid,       
  u.fname,
  u.lname,
  u.phone,
  u.email,
  u.country,
  COUNT(c.fid)    AS NoOfFriends
FROM coin AS c
  JOIN users AS u
    ON c.uid = u.id
GROUP BY c.uid
ORDER BY NoOfFriends desc
```

This query brings (as far as I know) the user with most invitations regardless of when his/her friends have registered.

So my question is: 
**Q1) How to apply the date condition into my query?**

I want the user who has the greatest number of friends invitation. His/her invited friends must have accepted the invitation and registered before 2012-08-31. Any other accepted invitations after that date should not be counted.

Please provide me with code examples.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Instead of asking two questions at once, it would be more clear if you asked just one question. If you have two questions then choose one and ask that one first. You can always create another question later if you still need more help. Make each of your questions clear, precise and self-contained, and avoid mixing up multiple things at once otherwise you'll just confuse yourself and everyone else.

Comment: Removed the first question. thanks for your comment.

Comment: " users must have registered before 31st of Oct 2012" Which table contains the registration date and what is the name of the column?

Comment: in table 'users' column date_create.

Comment: Do you want the total number of registrations AND the number of registrations until 31st Oct 2012 or just the latter? Can you show  what your desired result set should look like? You could even create an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to make it easy for us to see what you have and what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want the user how has the greatest number of friends invitation. His/her invited friends must have registered before 2012-08-31.Any other accepted invitations after that date will not be counted.

Comment: That's a completely different question from what you originally asked. Or your question was so poor that it was impossible to guess what you wanted from what you originally wrote. Please spend some time improving your question so that it matches what you have written in the comments. **And please include your desired result set in the question.** Consider writing an SQL fiddle. It might take you an extra 10 minutes to write a good question with an SQL fiddle, but if you had done that in the first place you'd already have the answer by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the answers confused the actual user with the invited friend.

```
SELECT
    c.uid
info.fname,
info.lname,
info.phone,
info.email,
info.country,
info.date_create,
    COUNT(c.fid) AS [NoOfFriends]
FROM coin AS c
    JOIN users AS friend
        ON c.fid = friend.id
    LEFT JOIN users AS info
        ON c.uid = info.id
WHERE friend.date_create < '20121031'
GROUP BY c.uid
```

**EDIT** Fixed the data format

Comment: Exactly. +1 for "A lot of the answers confused the actual user with the invited friend." Every time I try to get the date, i get the user create date not the date of invited friend.

Comment: Using culture specific date formats is not worthy of a down vote, but it almost is... Unless you are specifically setting a language/date format in your query you should use the culture inspecific format `yyyyMMdd` as there is no way this can be cast to an incorrect/invalid date.

Comment: @GarethD - Being technically correct is the best kind of correct. I will swallow my en-us pride and use a culture agnostic date format.

Comment: your answer is quite simpler than the rest, so by this, i will get the details of winners from info, while friend will count the number of friends from each member as uid. 
thanks.

Comment: btw, why you put NoOfFriends between square brackets? 
One more thing, I modified COUNT to COUNT(DISTINCT c.fid)  since it turned out that some users sent multiple invitation several times.

Comment: @Mohammed Joraid - You should probably put a UNIQUE NON-CLUSTERED index on COIN for the (UID, FID) columns to avoid having repeat records. I just put NoOfFriends in brackets out of a habit, there was no deeper meaning behind it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUM` in combination with `CASE`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN <cond> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NoOfFriends
```

The complete statement would look something like this:

```
SELECT
  c.uid,
  u.fname,
  u.lname,
  u.phone,
  u.email,
  u.country,
  u.`date_create`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f.date_create < 2012-10-31 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS NoOfFriends
FROM coin AS c
  JOIN users AS u
    ON c.uid = u.id
  join users as f
    on c.fid = f.id
GROUP BY c.uid, u.fname, u.lname, u.phone, u.email, u.country, u.`date_create`
ORDER BY NoOfFriends desc
```

Comment: Something else worth mentioning here, is that you will be able to filter "NoOfFriends" by using the HAVING clause after the group clause. (just for those who aren't aware of this)
The SUM/CASE combo is something which I really like and use.

Comment: You can also simplify it to `SUM(<cond>)` since boolean conditions evaluate to 1 or 0, although I think this may be a MySQL extension to SQL.

Comment: @Barmar: Indeed, that is a MySql extension. It wouldn't work in Oracle for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of only grouping by `c.uid` will work in MySQL, but you will become unstuck with other RDBMS.

In this situation I would move the count to a subquery, in my opinion it is easier to read, and it nicely separates out the query inot the logic you are looking to apply, i.e. Get all invites where the friend registered before a certain date, then joins back to the user that invited them.

```
SELECT  u.ID,
        u.fname,
        u.lname,
        u.phone,
        u.email,
        u.country,
        u.`date_create`,
        COALESCE(FriendCount, 0) AS FriendCount
        COALESCE(FriendCount2, 0) AS FriendCount2
FROM    users AS u
        LEFT JOIN  
        (   SELECT  coin.UID,
                    COUNT(coind.fid) AS FriendCount,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Users.Date_Create < '20121031' THEN coind.fid END) AS FriendCount2
            FROM    coin
                    INNER JOIN Users
                        ON coin.FID = users.ID
            GROUP BY coin.UID
        ) c
            ON c.uid = u.id
ORDER BY FriendCount2 DESC
```

If you do not care about total friends, and only those before 31st October then you can simplify this to

```
SELECT  u.ID,
        u.fname,
        u.lname,
        u.phone,
        u.email,
        u.country,
        u.`date_create`,
        COALESCE(FriendCount, 0) AS FriendCount
FROM    users AS u
        LEFT JOIN  
        (   SELECT  coin.UID,
                    COUNT(coind.fid) AS FriendCount
            FROM    coin
                    INNER JOIN Users
                        ON coin.FID = users.ID
            WHERE   Users.Date_Create < '20121031'
            GROUP BY coin.UID
        ) c
            ON c.uid = u.id
ORDER BY FriendCount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `count(expression)` function counts the rows where the result of that expression is not null. If the expression just returns true or false all rows will be counted because both true and false are not null.

To use an expression with count you must make it return null if false:

```
 COUNT(friend.date_create < '2012-10-31' or null) AS NoOfFriends
```

Comment: but date_create is in another field? how would the count access two tables and check. It needs to get fid from coin based on uid, and then see date_create in users for fid, if date is before 20120831 then it should be counted, otherwise, just move to the next fid related to the uid.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer, thanks for everyone who tried and helped, especially to LastCoder who provided an actual solution rapidly.

```
SELECT
  c.uid,
  info.id,
  info.fname,
  info.lname,
  info.phone,
  info.email,
  info.country,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.fid) AS NoOfFriends   -- modified this to get unique invitations
FROM coin c
  JOIN users AS friends
    ON c.fid = friends.id
  LEFT JOIN users AS info
    ON c.uid = info.id
WHERE friends.date_create < '20120831'
GROUP BY c.uid
ORDER BY NoOfFriends DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Honesty, i did not use other solutions because i don't understand  `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` clearly.